# How to do concatenation in excel?

Tags: excel

I am using excel concatenation to generate SQL insert statement but i find it very hard to define the concatenation for the below SQL values...can anyone advise? on the concatenation formula to use?

```
VALUES ( 
NEWID(),'ABC', 'ABC', 'ABC', 'abc', 'abc', 'abc', NULL,  CONVERT(datetime, '1999/01/01',     101)
,  CONVERT(datetime, '1999/12/31', 101), 1, 0, 1, LOWER(NEWID())
, 'abc',  getdate(), 'system'
,  getdate());
```

Comment: What exactly is your question? I don't see any concatenation above.  Excel concatenation is usually something like `="'" & A1 & "', '" & B1 & "'"`

Comment: You can google that. =CONCATENATE(A1,A2,A3) or =A1&A2&A3                   Take your pick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
="INSERT SOMETABLE VALUES ( \
NEWID(),'" & A2 & "', '" & B2 & "', 'ABC', 'abc', 'abc', 'abc', NULL, \
CONVERT(datetime, '1999/01/01',     101) \
,  CONVERT(datetime, '1999/12/31', 101), 1, 0, 1, LOWER(NEWID()) \
, 'abc',  getdate(), 'system' \
,  getdate());"
```

Note: When you see `\` in the above it means the line joins to the next line. The entire formula should be on a single line.

I have replaced the first two fixed values of "ABC" with `A2` and `B2` being cells from the sheet, e.g. you may have this formula in `X2`, which you would copy down.  If your cell values themselves can contain single quotes, it becomes more complicated and you'll need to add SUBSTITUTE to double them up.  e.g.

```
="INSERT SOMETABLE VALUES ( \
NEWID(),'" & SUBSTITUTE(A2,"'","''") & "', '" & B2 & "', 'ABC', 'abc', 'abc', 'abc', NULL, \
```

Comment: I dont really understand about the cell value contain single quote portion. Is it ok to explain further? Or show me an example?

Answer (score 0):

If Excel is trying to interpret/evaluate your SQL functions you may be out of luck with this approach.

Try setting up your insert SQL in a stored procedure, then have your excel file generate the stored procedure calls. Something like this:

```
spInsertRecord('ABC', 'ABC', 'ABC', 'abc', 'abc', 'abc', NULL,... etc)
```

This way you don't run into any issues with misinterpretation of embedded commands.

Hope this helps.